# SvelteKit Sass Missing Specifier

Tags: css, sass, svelte, sveltekit

In a new project I'm unable to reference CSS and SCSS from the `node_modules`.

e.g. trying to import a style sheet `media.scss` file from a library

```
<style lang="scss">
  @use "@dfinity/gix-components/dist/styles/mixins/media";
</style>
```

Result in following error when I try to open the app in my browser.

> Error: Missing "./dist/styles/mixins/media" specifier in "@dfinity/gix-components" package

Weirdly enough, if I provide a relative path to the file it works out.

```
<style lang="scss">
  @use "../../../node_modules/@dfinity/gix-components/dist/styles/mixins/media";
</style>
```

Therefore not sure what configuration should be set to help SvelteKit, Sass and Vite resolve correctly the style sheet. Has anyone faced the issue and knows how to solve it?